# PoWA-like web profiler for MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, profiling

[PoWA](http://dalibo.github.io/powa/) is a profiling tool for PostgreSQL using pg_stat_statment module and provide a very complete set of data in a web interface.

I'm searching an equivalent for MySQL, with a Web interface (or a separate tools who provide an interface), to profile requests performances and database general performances, but I can't find good tools for MySQL.

Someone would know a good profiling tool for mysql?